# Can I disable the IPython notebook to save the results into the ipynb file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I use the Jupyter 4.1.

I've found the results of the cells are also saved into the `ipynb` file. Can I disable it? I want manage it with Git.

For example, there is a cell of my notebook,

```
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 29,
   "metadata": {
    "autoscroll": "json-false",
    "collapsed": false,
    "ein.tags": [
     "worksheet-0"
    ],
    "slideshow": {
     "slide_type": "-"
    }
   },
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "2016-08-04 : 749591\n",
      "2016-08-05 : 447416\n",
      "2016-08-06 : 305969\n",
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "curidx = (data.cur_day - data.start_day).days\n",
    "for iday in range(curidx, data.nday):\n",
    "     day = data.cur_day + dt.timedelta(iday - curidx)\n",
    "     print \"%s : %d\"%(day, int(pdata.barCn[iday]))\n"
    ]
   }
```

I don't want the contents of the **outputs** to be saved.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: There are tools like [nbstripout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nbstripout) that can remove the outputs. You could configure a [save hook](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/savehooks.html) to change the notebook whenever it's saved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks @Thomas K, guided by his advice, I've found the solution that is use the [nbstripout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nbstripout). The usage is below

1. Install the nbstripout by pip.
2. cd to the dir of the notebook. If there is not a git repository, please init one.
3. Run `nbstripout --install` to install a git attribute filter which will strip out the outputs from the ipynb file when it's added to the git cache.